# Google Cloud Build & App Engine - Substitution Environmental Variables issue

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform

I deployed Flask app using App Engine and I want to deploy it with Google Cloud Build, that is triggered
on repository push.

In my Cloud Build trigger configuration I set substitution variables as follow:
_CLIENT_ID  
_CLIENT_SECRET 
etc.

This is my cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy']
  env:
    - 'CLIENT_ID=${_CLIENT_ID}'
    - 'CLIENT_SECRET=${_CLIENT_SECRET}'
    - 'REDIRECT_URI=${_REDIRECT_URI}'
    - 'SCOPE=${_SCOPE}'
timeout: '1600s'
```

Despite setting env those variables are not accessible from code - I still get "EMPTY" value instead of env value.

```
import os

CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID", "EMPTY")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET", "EMPTY")
```

I would really appreciate any help :)
Thanks!

I tried to set env variables from bash script (echo ${_CLIENT_ID} > /workspace/env_variables.yaml) in app.yaml I had includes: env_variables.yaml, but cloud build throws an error, that don't see env_variables.yaml

Comment: OK, I've managed via Storage Bucket as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502945/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-the-app-yaml-using-cloud-build?rq=2), but still - how should I use substitution variables then???

Comment: `gcloud app deploy` starts a new Cloud Build job to build a container with the current file. The environment variable are not set in the container. You have to update manually (or by code) the app.yaml file before running the `gcloud app deploy`. a SED is great for that.